# What is the minimum Xcode / iOS versions I should start with?

Tags: ios, xcode

Giving that there are many new features specially in memory management, I have iOS 4 / 5 books  and there are links to tutorials everywhere for them.

What is the minimum that I should read to take advantage of new features and do not have to 'unlearn' stuffs found in newer versions?

**EDIT:**
There are some good books about iOS 4/5. Should I avoid them?

Comment: You have to support iOS 7 (which requires Xcode 5) if you plan to submit an app to Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the newest `SDK` and developer tools, `Xcode 5`. Learn about what's possible with `iOS 7` and `iOS 6`. Don't spend too much time on `iOS 4` and `5`. Focus on learning about frameworks and not on particular OS versions.

You should still learn about old-style memory management, `release` and `retain` methods to understand how `ARC` is dealing with them for you. However, don't spend too much time on reading. Start coding. Nothing will replace a hands on experience and you learn much quicker when you deal with real projects and real problems.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on iOS 7. There is a quite a bit different in iOS 7 from previous versions, spending time on previous versions is only going to confuse you and make it harder to learn.

Focus on a project and get it built, thats the best way to learn.